# Can wide IPv6 adoption make technologies like ECH obsolete?

Tags: encryption, tls, cloudflare

[Encrypted Client Hello](https://tlswg.org/draft-ietf-tls-esni/draft-ietf-tls-esni.html) (ECH) encrypts the whole Client hello and because of that ISPs won't know which website any given user intends to visit unless the website is using a dedicated IP address and the ISP have already associated the IP address with the given websites.

Nowadays because of IPv4 addresses shortage and shared usage this can't always be the case for users using ECH, but after wide adoption of IPv6, even reverse proxy services like [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/) can assign a single IPv6 address to each website and make the Client Hello encryption useless.

Now, considering the active development of the [ECH draft](https://github.com/tlswg/draft-ietf-tls-esni), am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's true that a 1:1 mapping of certificate to IP address would defeat the purpose of ECH, I think it's unlikely that large hosts like Cloudflare are going to suddenly give each user their own IPv6 address.  First of all, those IP addresses have to be bound to some network card, and at least in the past, Linux has run into scale problems when you have tens of thousands of IPv6 addresses.  There's no functional reason that they can't continue to serve data over a small set of IPs, so they probably will continue to do so, because it vastly simplifies infrastructure.

The place that IPv6 addresses are most useful in their plenty is when connecting outbound.  NAT is not required, and infrastructure like SMTP servers, where reputation can be associated with an IP, benefits more from multiple IPv6 addresses.

Of course, I don't work for Cloudflare or a similar large proxy service, but I have worked in the shared web hosting industry, and my experience tells me that HTTPS doesn't benefit that much from having each site on its own IPv6 address, while SMTP does.

Answer (score 1):

If there's a 1:1 mapping between name in certificate and IP address, I can simply connect to that IP and ask for the certificate, to know which site the user attempts to visit. That won't really improve privacy over clear-text SNI's - which is what ECH attempts to do.